# Why can't I download a .gif attached to an email in the Gmail app?

Tags: gmail

Example:

[image]

"Save" is greyed out.

Using Android 10 and Samsung Galaxy S9.

Comment: I am sorry but your question has too many (confusing) screen shots and too little description. Please describe in details what you want to do and what app(s) you are using.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior seems to be a bug: the "save" is not greyed out at first, when it does become greyed out after clicking on "save". And strangely,  the "download again" is also greyed out even after clicking on save. Also the user interface seems to use the terms save and download interchangeably, which gives an inconsistent user interface.

[image]